# Retrieve time difference since last action -- python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, aggregation, shift

Let's say I have purchase records with two fields Buy and Time.

What I want to get is the third column of time elapsed since first not-buy so it looks like:

```
buy| time | time difference
1  | 8:00 | NULL
0  | 9:01 | NULL
0  | 9:10 | NULL
0  | 9:21 | NULL
1  | 9:31 | 0:30
0  | 9:41 | NULL
0  | 9:42 | NULL
1  | 9:53 | 0:12
```

How can I achieve this? It seems to me that it's a mix of pd.groupby() and pd.shift(), but I can't seem to work that out in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)


df.loc[df.buy==1,'DIFF']=df.groupby(df.buy.cumsum().shift().fillna(0)).time.transform(lambda x : x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
df
Out[19]: 
   buy                time timedifference     DIFF
0    1 2018-02-26 08:00:00            NaN 00:00:00
1    0 2018-02-26 09:01:00            NaN      NaT
2    0 2018-02-26 09:10:00            NaN      NaT
3    0 2018-02-26 09:21:00            NaN      NaT
4    1 2018-02-26 09:31:00           0:30 00:30:00
5    0 2018-02-26 09:41:00            NaN      NaT
6    0 2018-02-26 09:42:00            NaN      NaT
7    1 2018-02-26 09:53:00           0:12 00:12:00

#df.buy.cumsum().shift().fillna(0) Create the key for groupby 

#time.transform(lambda x : x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0]) create the different for each group
#df.loc[df.buy==1,'DIFF'] fill the value from groupby by the right position which buy equal to 1
```

Comment: @eatkimchi if this is what you need can you consider accept and upvote ? thank

Comment: I up-voted your answer @Wen .. would you mind editing your answer to walk through that one line of code? I'm learning Pandas and replicated this dataframe on Jupyter, and trying to understand each part of your code. An explanation would be great, such as what `x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0]` is referencing exactly per time value, and whether we can apply the same to buy==0 in general

Comment: @rishijd adding some explanation , for you second part question in comment , pandas is index sensitive which mean when we assign a new value , we just need to make sure the index is same for both side and give the condition we need to assign

Comment: Thank you @Wen. Still trying to understand, but when I apply `df.groupby(['buy']).time.transform(lambda x : x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])` (the groupby here gives us 2 groups - 0 and 1) - I am getting values like: 

`0   01:53:00
1   00:41:00
2   00:41:00
3   00:41:00
4   01:53:00
5   00:41:00
6   00:41:00
7   01:53:00`

I can see the time difference here is from the first time to the last time for each "buy" index, and it seems the times inbetween are ignored. Shouldn't it go through one time at a time and get the difference from the previous time entry?

Comment: @rishijd since you only need the *first not-buy*, this will be the solution only target the firs not buy to the backward 1st buy time, that is why iloc[0] and iloc[-1]

Comment: Oh right, of course :) I'll keep working with the code to fully understand the rest. Thank you :)